# Tkinter save files and re-open files

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an Python GUI built with Tkinter that has several widgets(scroll-boxes, entry boxes, check-boxes, etc). For this project, since not all of the information will be completed in one go, I need a way to save what is in the widgets, and then be able to fill it in again where the user left off at by opening the saved file. As I am still relatively new to Python, I am just trying to get a feel for what you all have done to accomplish this in the simplest way. I have heard of saving info in XML, using the shelve module, just saving as txt... Since I cannot use SQL for this, just looking for a way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up on this. I tried using shelve but ended up using Pickle. It was
fairly straightforward and produced the results I wanted. I can save the input from
the user in the entry boxes/radio buttons, scrollboxes, etc. and then re-open the
binary file and "restore" the input to those widgets.

```
    import pickle as pk
    """Open File"""
    def file_open():
        designer_open_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="C:/",
            defaultextension=".gd",
            filetypes=(("GD", "*.gd"), ("All files", "*"))
    )
    if designer_open_file is None:
        return

    saved_gd_data = pk.load(open(designer_open_file, "rb"))
    open_designer = saved_gd_data["gd_designer"]
    designer_nameE.delete(0, END)
    designer_nameE.insert(0, open_designer)
    
    more data collected below...

    """Save Data"""
    def file_save():
        designer_save_file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(
            initialdir="C:/", mode="w",
            defaultextension=".db",
            filetypes=(("GD", "*.gd"), ("All files", "*"))
    )
    if designer_save_file is None:
        return

    gd_save_name = designer_save_file.name
    basename = os.path.basename(gd_save_name)
    path = os.path.dirname(gd_save_name)

    gd_data = {"gsd_designer": designer_nameE.get(), "gd_design": design_nameE.get(), 
    etc, etc.

    pk.dump(gd_data, open(path + "/" + basename, "wb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you want to save, I would, in addition to xml, recommend to look into [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which both come with pyhton and are rather straight forward.

I am not really sure if this is in the scope of your question or if you already solved this, but you mentioned saving and loading data back into the widgets. Regarding this, the tkinter [Variable classes and the trace mehthod](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) are pretty useful. The latter could also be used to verify input data (minumum password length, etc)

Comment: Thank you r0w. I will look into those options. Someone also mentioned cPickle so I guess there is that as well. Just looking to save the data and re-open and fill in the entry boxes/Text widgets etc. when the app is opened again. Thank you so much for the suggestions.